# In python, determine if display support only text or if graphics are available

Tags: python

I have some python scripts that embed matlibplot.py.  I run these on desktop for development, test, demonstration, and operations where they display matlibplot figures. However, I also am running these on servers where there is no graphics display, only terminal mode or in the background with output redirect.

I have set an option (manually) in the scripts's as a command line option.  I would like to automatically determine (in a general way - not specific to displays and graphics such as X) if graphics are available through code. Is anyone doing this or know the snippet to perform this check?

Comment: You want  to now if the system has a graphic card in python, is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together a small function to detect if a graphic card exists on `windows` or `linux`, i.e.:

```
import subprocess, os

def gc_available():
    if os.name == 'nt': # Windows
        import wmi 
        try: 
            wmi.WMI().computer.Win32_VideoController()[0] # Tested on Windows 10
            return 1
        except:
            pass

    elif os.name == 'posix': # Linux
        out = subprocess.getoutput('sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration') # Tested on CENTOS 7 and Ubuntu
        if out:
            return 1
```

---

Usage:

```
if gc_available():
    print("VideoController available")
else:
    print("VideoController Not available")
```

Comment: But if I `ssh` to a cluster node (possibly armed with multiple GPUs), this would still claim `"VideoController available"`, would it not?

Comment: @dedObed Not sure, I'd have to test it, can you do it on a `cluster node`? OP never mentioned a **cluster node**, still, I'm curious to know the result.

Comment: At least that's what I understood by "running these on servers where there is no graphics display". Being in a cluster or not is, I guess, not that important, those machines just lack any VGA/HDMI/whatever output devices, don't run X server etc.

Comment: Pedro, this works well for my application, both in linux and windows as you designed.  I ran several tests and it performed as needed. Thank you much for your quick response!!!!!

Comment: you're welcome @TurnerLittle! GL. If my answer helped you, please accept it as the correct answer. Thank you!